Adding subplot titles using plotly and annotations doesn't work
From this post it became clear that to add titles to each subplot using plotly the annotations in layout argument should be used. However in my case it doesn't seem to work, why not?
Reproducible example:
# the data
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5), fruit = c(788, 911, 181, 111, 900), vegetable = c(666, 777, 888, 999, 1000), sex = c("men","women","men","men","women"), age = c(17, 84, 67, 4, 35))
age_min_max <- list(c(0, 79))
all_nut_labels <- c("fruit","vegetable")
  
# defining a function to return a subplot with a dynamic number of plots 
f.make.plots <- function(df, age_min_max, all_nut_labels){
  
  # initialize an empty list to store the plots
  plot_list <- list()
  
  # extract min and max age
  for (ages in age_min_max){
    min_age <- ages[1] + 1
    max_age <- ages[2] 
    
    # loop through each combination of min_age, max_age, and nut_label
    for (nut_label in all_nut_labels){
      
      age_group <- paste0(min_age, "_", max_age)

      # Get the data for men
      the_data <- df[df$sex == "men", c("age", nut_label)]

      # create a scatter plot
      fig <- plot_ly(data = the_data, x = ~ age, y = ~ the_data[[nut_label]], type = "scatter", mode = "markers", marker = list(size = 10), showlegend = FALSE)
      
      # set y-axis name and title
      dynamic_title <- paste0("Original data for ", nut_label, "\n", "men", "; age ", min_age, "-", max_age)
      dynamic_y_name <- paste0(nut_label, "intakes")
      
      fig <- layout(fig, yaxis = list(title = dynamic_y_name))
      
      # add the subplot titles
      fig %>%
        add_annotations(
          text = ~dynamic_title,
          x = 0.5,
          y = 1,
          yref = "paper",
          xref = "paper",
          xanchor = "middle",
          yanchor = "top",
          showarrow = FALSE,
          font = list(size = 15)
        )

      men_plot_name <- paste0("original_data_", nut_label, "_men_", age_group)
      plot_list[[men_plot_name]] <- fig
      
    }
  }
  
  the_subplots <- plot_list %>% subplot(nrows = NROW(.))
  
  return(the_subplots)
}

# creating a list of plotly plots
plot_list <- f.make.plots(df, age_min_max, all_nut_labels)

This is what it returns, where are the subplot titles?


Try with fig <- fig %>% add_annotations(...) to store the figure with the annotations as fig.
